# Images not displaying - JSP web app

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to display images for artists on a index.jsp. 
My  tag looks like this..

```
    <img src="Image?type=event&id=${event.ID}">
```

I use the event id to get the correct image from the database.
My image servlet code is as follows

```
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    if (type.equals("event"))
    {
        ISocial soc = DesktopWrapper.getInstance().getParentEvent(Integer.parseInt(id));
        BufferedImage image = soc.getImage(0);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int contentLength = byteStream.size();
        byte[] bytes = byteStream.toByteArray();


        response.setContentType("image/png");
        response.setContentLength(contentLength);
        OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(bytes);


    }
```

I have also tried using ImageIO but that also doesn't work. The images do not show up when the page is requested and I don't have any idea why!

I have read other threads already which this is marked as a duplicate off and have used ImageIO to to write the image to a ByteStream, however images are still not displaying.

Thanks.

```
 String type = request.getParameter("type");
    String id = request.getParameter("id");

    if (type.equals("event"))
    {
        ISocial soc = DesktopWrapper.getInstance().getParentEvent(Integer.parseInt(id));
        BufferedImage image = soc.getImage(0);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteStream);
        byte[] bytes = byteStream.toByteArray();
        int contentLength = byteStream.size();

        response.setContentType("image/jpg");
        response.setContentLength(contentLength);
        OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(bytes);
       // ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", stream);

    }
```

Comment: is the source good? have you tried to see/print if event.ID is ok?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you get the wrong image path... the servlet path is probably not relative to index.jsp.

Comment: You could try to debug by printing  image.getWidth() and image.getHeight()